# Payment IPN - Payment Integration Issue - Multiple subscriptions on 1 paypal account

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, cart

I have an issue with our PayPal checkout system that we can't seem to figure out. Here is the problem.

Let me setup the scenario properly:

```
User A = Office Manager of 3 realtors

User B = A realtor at that office

User C = Another realtor at the same office

User A is in charge of purchasing the upgrades to all of the realtors in this particular office (Users B &C).
```

In our system User A would have to login to their account click to the appropriate cart and checkout. This takes them to a PayPal checkout. They sign in and confirm their purchase. This is a subscription that last for X days.

Now, that user logs out and logs in with User B (because they are the office manager) account and goes to the checkout. They login with the same PayPal account they had used previously to purchase upgrade on User A. They confirm the purchase.

So, lets reflect on what we have thus far. User A has logged in with PayPal account 1 and purchased two separate subscriptions from our service. Each having their own unique credentials.

Let’s move on,

User A now logs into User C account and repeats the steps checking out with the same PayPal account, again.

All is good up to this point because no one has cancelled their subscription payment. Now this is where it gets a little tricky.

User B tells the office manager they no longer want their account to be upgraded and ask the manager to handle it. User A (the manager) logs into that PayPal account used to purchase all of the subscriptions within that office and cancels User B subscription.

Now that this action has taken place this is where we are running into issues. Because all of the subscriptions were purchased under this one account when the time of renewal comes the IPN notice we receive is not individually identifying the purchases. It is basically saying that a payment was made on the account (because User A and User C) still have active subscriptions. So on our end the system thinks User B is still active and they get a “free” upgrade that should have cancelled.

I hope I explained this well enough. Maybe it’s a simple adjustment we need to make so that the information received from PayPal allows us to identify properly between the 3 payments and keep active only the accounts that have made a renewal payment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In short, you should be paying attention to the subscription ID (`subscr_id`) that comes back in each IPN — that will uniquely identify each subscription.

- When each user creates their subscriptions, you should be getting an IPN with `txn_type` set to `subscr_signup`, and a subscription ID in `subscr_id`.
- Each time a subscription payment is processed, you should be getting an IPN with `txn_type` set to `subscr_payment`, and the relevant subscription ID in `subscr_id`.
- When user B cancels, you'll get an IPN with `txn_type` set to `subscr_cancel`, letting you know that they cancelled their subscription.  (The subscription ID will be in `subscr_id`.)
- When the term of user B's subscription expires, you'll get an IPN with `txn_type` set to `subscr_eot` (and again, the subscription ID in `subscr_id`).  Once you get this IPN, you can deactivate the upgrade on this user's account.

So, if you keep track of each subscription ID and which user it belongs to, it should be pretty easy to figure out who's paying and who isn't.

Comment: We have tried that with no success. :) Any other ideas on what might figure it out?

Comment: What part of it exactly hasn't been working?  Are you not receiving any IPNs at all?  Are you not getting particular IPNs?  Or are you not receiving subscription IDs in the IPNs?

Comment: Please see the response by debojit. I have invited them to the conversation because they are they the one that know more about what is connected and not connected from the IPN. The issue is unique because it occurs when a 2 or more subscriptions have been purchased on one paypal account. In testing the subscriptions are being purchased on the same day and last the same amount of time. I am testing the duration at 1 day in live accounts and we have not been able to solve the cause of this glitch for sometime now. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I noticed today when teasing on a live account that the profile  ID created on the subscription did something I had not noticed until today. Here are the actions: 1) paid for a subscription. This created a action within the paypal account for created and completed. Create profile ID was different than the complete Profile ID. I immediately canceled the payment now a cancel action was recorded. That profile ID was the same as the created ID. Why does the completed profile ID differ although linked to the some subscription?

Comment: Hi @CaptainObvious, can you provide me with a profile ID?  I'd like to research this a little more on my end.

Comment: The Create and Cancel Profile ID's were - Profile ID No. I-HYREJKMYRESK and the completed Profile ID was Profile ID No. I-FVYVFK97W0PR - This is on the notifications from within the users paypal account on the transactions page.

Comment: When the emails came from paypal that the user had created a new automatic profile the ID in that email was I-FVYVFK97W0PR and even when they canceled the subscription and got the email it was I-FVYVFK97W0PR. Which is weird because in the account transactions summary under the cancel activity it was Profile ID No. I-HYREJKMYRESK. So in the end I suppose Profile ID No. I-HYREJKMYRESK and Profile ID No. I-FVYVFK97W0PR are the same?

Comment: Could I get you to create a ticket at https://www.paypal.com/mts and provide me with the ticket number?

Comment: If possible, please also include the HTML code for the subscription button in your ticket.

Comment: Do you think that the subscription button code could cause this?

Comment: I don't think so, but I want to be sure.  Plus it'll help me to replicate the issue on my end.

Comment: I filed the ticket using the same info that was provided here. Paypal support's answer was amusing and frustrating at the same time: Thank you for contacting Merchant Technical Services. Yes, it is the same and it could have happen due to some technical error. But, it just a conflict, nothing happen will be impacted.
I hope this clarifies and answered.

Comment: What was the ticket number?

Answer (score 0):

the problem we are facing in this case is that when we cancel one account then the other account also become canceled in this case.We have seted as you mentioned.Payment has been done from the same paypal account for all those users.

Comment: Hi @debojit, can you clarify which is happening -- is it the case that when the buyer tries to cancel one subscription on PayPal, both of them are canceled?  Or is it the case that the buyer goes to PayPal and cancels one subscription, but both of the user upgrades are being canceled on your system?

Comment: Hello Matt, We are giving a scenario here.Say there are two user A and B.Both are using same paypal id(Example: abcd@gmail.com) for purchase a subscription product.Timing(purchasing) of A= 13apr 10am,B= 13apr 10.15am.At 10.30 am A cancels the subscription.So A should have that product till 14 apr 10am and B should continue(subscription renew each day ).But we see that after one day on 14 apr around 11 am both of the subscriptions get cancelled(A and B).We setup the functionality just like you mentioned.But we are facing this problem.Can you please mention that what is going wrong here?Thanks.